# C Making volatile sig_atomic_t Global in Header File

Tags: c, global, volatile, sigint, sig-atomic-t

I'm trying to make a global variable, initialized in my msh.c file as:

```
volatile sig_atomic_t sig_int = 0;
```

This alone seems to be fine. However if I go to my proto.h file(which is included in all the c files for this project), and type:

```
extern volatile sig_atomic_t sig_int;
```

It throws a bunch of errors:

```
gcc -c -Wall msh.c arg_parse.c builtin.c expand.c
In file included from arg_parse.c:5:
proto.h:3: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘sig_int’
In file included from builtin.c:13:
proto.h:3: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘sig_int’
In file included from expand.c:11:
proto.h:3: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘sig_int’
make: *** [msh.o] Error 1
```

How exactly do I make this variable global? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `proto.h` file needs to include `<signal.h>` so that the `sig_atomic_t` type is defined, that's all.